# NetBeans use custom code templates for a TWIG file

Tags: symfony, templates, netbeans, twig, code-templates

In my twig view files for a Symfony application I need to write a log `{% trans %}Foo Bar Baz{% endtrans %}` what is quite annoying.

Therefore I tried to make a template, where I just have to write `trans` press space and the magic is done.

I made a new Template in `Twig File`, `Twig Block` and `Twig Variable` but non of them worked. The Code I used was:

```
{% trans %}${TEXT}{% endtrans %}
```

Abbreviation is `trans`

Then I restarted NetBeans, but unfortunately nothing happens when I write `trans` in a .twig file.

What am I doing wrong? How do I have to do this?

Thanks (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your Code Template in the Twig Block language, not Twig File language.

[image]

You don't need to reboot netbeans.

Then, type relatively quickly: {% tr<kbd>enter</kbd>

You'll come up with:

[image]

If you don't want to type `{%` at all, you can choose HTML language instead of Twig Block language (assuming your file name ends with `.html.twig`).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a `Twig Markup`. All I have is `Twig File`, `Twig Block` and `Twig Variable`. I'm using NetBeans 8.0.2 with the `Twig Templates` plugin in version 1.20.1. Do I need another plugin?

Comment: I think `Twig Block` is good. But replace `{% trans %}${TEXT}{% endtrans %}` by `trans %}${TEXT}{% endtrans %}` (removing the left side).

Comment: and just `tr` or `{% tr` as Abbreviation?

Comment: yep. The shorter it is, the quicker you'll type it.

Comment: So I made it work thanks to your assistance. As Abbrevation I've put `t` (it's shorter than `tr` ;)) and as Expanded Text `trans %}${TEXT}{% endtrans %}`. Now I just have to write `{% t` and press tab to get `{% trans %}{% endtrans %}` with the cursor between the trans tags. The only thing left, I'm wondering about, is there a way to achive it without writing `{% `, so just `t` and tab?

Comment: Nope. Twig can contain HTML, Javascript or whatever, so other completions might apply (example, Javascript if your file ends by `.js.twig`), not specific to Twig language.

Comment: Just found it out my self. A `.html.twig` file is recognized as html file, so you're able to add a code template for the HTML language with Abbreviation: `t` and Expanded Text: `{% trans %}${TEXT}{% endtrans %}` it will work like a charm!

Comment: Answer is accepted. Could you may update it to add the `Twig Block` and the possibility to add it tho the HTML language?